# ORA--07445 error during online Re-org process in 10.2.0.4 database

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, maintenance

I was doing re-org of fragmented tables in an Oracle 10.2.0.4 production database:

```
sys@CLARITY> ALTER TABLE SOP_QUEUE ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
Table altered

sys@CLARITY> ALTER TABLE SOP_QUEUE SHRINK SPACE CASCADE;
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
```

When I checked the alert log, I found the following error:

```
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ktsk_get_prevl2()+217] 
[SIGSEGV] [Address not mapped to object] [0x2E97317530] [] []
```

What could be the reason for this error, as I am unable to find a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Bug 6494048 - Dump [ktsk_get_prevl2] from ALTER INDEX .. SHRINK SPACE (Doc ID 6494048.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=753035.1&id=6494048.8)

```
This issue is fixed in

11.2.0.1 (Base Release)
10.2.0.5 (Server Patch Set)
```

Upgrade from that ancient, unsupported version.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion. As for few tables it worked fine but when i placed a larger table having size around 15 to 20GB, this issue was encountered. Is there something which i can check at OS(HP-UX B11.23) level to troubleshoot the issue?